# cPanel to LAMP FTP woes, how to configure/use ProFTPD like cPanel does?

Tags: ftp

so yesterday I made the move to stop using cPanel on my CentOS 6 server and learn how to use it using a LAMP sertup.

My basic requirement was to just have a web server with ftp access for me and my registered users, I use atmail for my mailing and another server running mysql server on it.

cPanel was just over the top in that aspect, so I moved to LAMP. Now my issue is that I want to be able to make FTP users and lock them into their "home" directory such as `/var/www/html/users/<user>`

these are the steps I have taken:

> 1) wget proftpd-1.3.3e.tar.gz (from ftp repo)
>
> 2) tar zxvf proftpd-1.3.3e.tar.gz
>
> 3) cd /proftpd-1.3.3e.tar.gz
>
> 4) ./configure
>
> 5) make
>
> 6) make install
>
> I edited /etc/proftpd.conf to this
>   7) vi /etc/proftpd.conf
>
> 8) DefaultRoot ~
>
> 9) User     nobody
>
> Group    nobody

thats as far as I have gotten, I attemped to make a user with this command

> 10) groupadd test
>
> 11) useradd -g test1 -p test1 -d /var/www/html/users/ -s
>   /sbin/false test

i tried to login, but Filezilla throws a login incorrect error.

I have looked at maybe 20 guides on how to set up ProFTPD but I am still confused and has been nothing but a learning experience for me.

Can someone perhaps tell me the exact steps needed to get a successful FTP server running much like cPanel sets up when adding FTP accounts.

Edit: this is my proftpd.conf

```
# This is a basic ProFTPD configuration file (rename it to
# 'proftpd.conf' for actual use.  It establishes a single server
# and a single anonymous login.  It assumes that you have a user/group
# "nobody" and "ftp" for normal operation and anon.

ServerName                      "ProFTPD Default Installation"
ServerType                      standalone
DefaultServer                   on

# Port 21 is the standard FTP port.
Port                            21

# Don't use IPv6 support by default.
UseIPv6                         off

# Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new dirs and files
# from being group and world writable.
Umask                           022

# To prevent DoS attacks, set the maximum number of child processes
# to 30.  If you need to allow more than 30 concurrent connections
# at once, simply increase this value.  Note that this ONLY works
# in standalone mode, in inetd mode you should use an inetd server
# that allows you to limit maximum number of processes per service
# (such as xinetd).
MaxInstances                    30

# Set the user and group under which the server will run.
User                            nobody
Group                           nobody

# To cause every FTP user to be "jailed" (chrooted) into their home
# directory, uncomment this line.
DefaultRoot ~

# Normally, we want files to be overwriteable.
AllowOverwrite          on

# Bar use of SITE CHMOD by default
<Limit SITE_CHMOD>
  DenyAll
</Limit>

# A basic anonymous configuration, no upload directories.  If you do not
# want anonymous users, simply delete this entire <Anonymous> section.
#<Anonymous ~ftp>
#  User                         ftp
#  Group                                ftp

  # We want clients to be able to login with "anonymous" as well as "ftp"
#  UserAlias                    anonymous ftp

  # Limit the maximum number of anonymous logins
#  MaxClients                   10

  # We want 'welcome.msg' displayed at login, and '.message' displayed
  # in each newly chdired directory.
#  DisplayLogin                 welcome.msg
#  DisplayChdir                 .message

  # Limit WRITE everywhere in the anonymous chroot
#  <Limit WRITE>
#    DenyAll
#  </Limit>
#</Anonymous>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set `AuthOrder` to `mod_auth_pam.c* mod_auth_unix.c` in `proftpd.conf`?

You can also setup [virtual users](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/VirtualUsers.html) with [ftpasswd](http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/contrib/ftpasswd.html).

---

If you still cannot login, enable the log:

```
# Define the log formats
LogFormat           default "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b"
LogFormat           auth    "%v [%P] %h %t \"%r\" %s"

# Define log-files to use
TransferLog /var/log/proftpd/xferlog
ExtendedLog /var/log/proftpd/access_log WRITE,READ write
ExtendedLog /var/log/proftpd/auth_log AUTH auth
ExtendedLog /var/log/proftpd/paranoid_log ALL default
```

to see what happens.

Comment: Add `AuthOrder` directive as I suggested above, restart `proftpd` and try again.

Comment: didn't work, how can i add a group and assign a ew user to that group?

Comment: _"didn't work"_ is not good reply. You should give us the error you get. Anyway, you can add a group with `groupadd` and add an user to that group by `useradd -g <group> <user>`.

Comment: hehe, ya well there isn't much to say. I am unable to connect using Filezilla, how would i abel able to check what users exists? i added a few users with `useradd` but im starting to think that its not adding them correctly. i used `groupadd`  to add a "test" group but when i include the group in the useradd it returns and error saying that user 'test' doesn't exist

Comment: `useradd` creates a new user. There is no reason for that error _"user 'test' doesn't exist"_. Please give us the exactly command you use and output you get?

Comment: @s2xi let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1069/discussion-between-quanta-and-s2xi)